# crypt(param_1,local_88) function in C Secure?

Tags: c, crypt

Security scan tool reported C's crypt(param_1,local_88) as dangerous function. Searching in google couldn't find any solid information on crypt except someone mentioned it uses DES which is 64 bit (not 3DES) encryption. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Which security scan tool? Why is it dangerous?

Comment: And `crypt()` isn't part of the C standard. It's POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

The Unix/POSIX C function `crypt` is a long-obsolete password hashing mechanism. While calling it isn't dangerous in itself (unlike, say, `gets()`) — at least no more than any other C function (so you need to pay attention to pointer validity and buffer sizes) — relying on it to have any security properties whatsoever is dangerous. So if you're calling `crypt()`, it's a strong sign that your application is doing something wrong.

The name and documentation date back from the 1970s when computer-era cryptography  was very new and using cryptography for anything other than encryption was unfamiliar. It isn't encryption because it's a one-way thing: you can't go back from its output to the input except by brute force (trying all possible inputs and calling `crypt()` until the output matches).

`crypt()` is dangerous because brute force is feasible, it's too fast, and its salt is too small. (Read [How to securely hash passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) if you want to know the background.) The input “key” (actually a password) is only 8 bytes, out of which 8 bits are ignored. The input space is even smaller if the input is made of printable characters, and even smaller if the input has some structure (e.g. a known mix of punctuation vs letters). It can typically be brute-forced in hours.

`crypt()` has been obsolete since the mid-1990s. If you need to hash a password, you are long overdue for [switching to a modern method](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193351/in-2018-what-is-the-recommended-hash-to-store-passwords-bcrypt-scrypt-argon2). If you're using `crypt()` for some other purpose, it's probably wrong too — I can't think of anything useful `crypt()` can do in the 21st century — and you should ask a professional what to do instead. (Don't ask on Stack Overflow which is not good at cryptography. [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptograhy SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) can give good advice.)

Comment: The links you provided don't have up-to-date answers as of 2022.